# R rename column name as CSV name in loop?

Tags: r

I have something like 5,000 CVS's and each CSV is named as the date; 20080101.csv, 20080102.csv, 20080103.csv etc. I'm trying to loop through them all and replace a column name in each with the date. I can't for the life of me figure out how to grab the CSV names from the loop to change the column name. I have a feeling this is a simple thing to do. Below is my attempted code. Thanks for any help

```
setwd("C:/Desktop/Rain_totals")
fs <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
for (f in fs) {
  df <- read.csv(f)
  colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="MEAN"] <- df
  write.csv(df, gsub('.csv', '_formatted.csv', f))
}
```

Comment: The line `colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="MEAN"] <- df` tries to write the whole data frame into the column name currently set as "MEAN". Instead you want to use `fs` with `.csv` removed. You will have to quote these character strings whenever you use them in code so it would be preferable to prefix the date with a character, e.g. "D" as in `paste0("D", gsub("\\.csv", "", "20080101.csv"))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package stringR

```
str_remove(string = "msr.csv", pattern = ".csv")

"msr"
```